# IBM MQ upgrade causing error 2059 and error 2018

Tags: c++, linux, ibm-mq

In my application one interface is connected to external system on MQ. When MQ upgrade is performed by system team from MQ version 7.5 to version 8.0 we are facing error 2059 and error 2018. We could see the below error in our log file.

error from log :-

```
18.07.24 19:49:11 [mqseries:14610]mqs_process_mb_msg:**MQCONN ended with reason code 2059** 
18.07.24 19:49:11 [mqseries:14610]mqs_exit: signal 0 received
18.07.24 19:49:11 [mqseries:14610]**ABST.ONLINE.PUT.DBSI.Q Disconnected** 
18.07.24 19:49:11 [mqseries:14610]**MQCLOSE ABST.ONLINE.PUT.DBSI.Q ended with reason 2018** 
18.07.24 19:49:11 [mqseries:14610]**MQDISC ended with reason code 2018**
```

Please note once the system team is downgrading it back to MQ version 7.5 it is working fine and as expected. Kindly help on what could be the missing during the MQ upgrade from version 7.5 to version 8.

Comment: What does the error log on the queue manager show?  What specific v8.0.0.x do they upgrade to? What specific version is your MQ client?

Comment: You only get 2018, because you are trying to close a connection not opened correctly. Your only error code seems to be 2059, wich suggests the QM isn’t actually running when “migrated”. Have you checked the QM error logs?

Comment: MQ versions below for your reference:-

$dspmqver -a
Name:        WebSphere MQ
Version:     8.0.0.9
Level:       p800-009-180321.1
BuildType:   IKAP - (Production)
Platform:    WebSphere MQ for Linux (x86-64 platform)
Mode:        64-bit
O/S:         Linux 2.6.32-754.6.3.el6.x86_64
InstName:    Installation1
InstDesc:
Primary:     Yes
InstPath:    /opt/mqm
DataPath:    /var/mqm
MaxCmdLevel: 802
--------------------------------------------------------

$rpm -qa | grep MQSeriesClient
MQSeriesClient-8.0.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesClient-U8009-8.0.0-9.x86_64

Comment: Both of us asked for what the QM error logs have,  can you provide?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your software is compatible with MQ 8.0.
I had a similar issue. It turned out that we needed to upgrade to Java 8.

Comment: I checked in IBM website, for MQ 8 Java 7 seems to be compatible. Are you saying this is causing the issue? Any error log which I can check to confirm ?

Currently this is the version :- 

java version "1.7.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.15.4.el6_10-x86_64 u191-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.191-b01, mixed mode)